# How to fix System data pdb not loaded

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am geting this error when

```
return(t.Fill(sqlnsConnectionString, String.Format(" SELECT  * FROM List   {0} ", filter)))
```

How to fix data.pdb not loaded

[image]

Comment: can you give the stack trace?

Comment: I do not know how to give

Answer (score 15):

To "fix" you'd need the System.Data pdb but if you don't want to be nagged by the message telling you it can't locate the .pdb file, you can try

Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General

check the box for "Enable just My Code".

Comment: this did the work for me!

Answer (score 6):

Indeed, the activation of the "Enable Just My Code" and deactivation of Enable .NET Framework source stepping solved the issue!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Add this line **useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true"** to your App.config file in start up tag like this  below

2. Enable Just my code.
   Go to

   - tool
   - then Option
   - then Debugging
   - then General
   - mark check for Enable just my code